# FormsAuthentication with dynamic roles

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, form-authentication

i have a application with a roles table and a permission (user permissions per form)  table different roles has different access levels and each user has specific access permissions to each form .
can i implement it using FormsAuthentication ?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the list or roles to `FormsAuthenticationTicket`

Here is the complete code, I have added comments as well.

```
protected void lbtnSignIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 .......Login credential checking code......
 .......If the use verified, then add the roles to FormsAuthenticationTicket 
 .......I am assuming in the below code, you are getting list of roles from DB in DataTable
 String roles = String.Empty;
 if (dtblUsersRoles.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
     for (int count = 0; count < dtblUsersRoles.Rows.Count; count++)
     {
      //build list of roles in comma seperate
      roles = roles + "," + dtblUsersRoles.Rows[count]["RoleName"].ToString();
     }
    }

FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, txtUserID.Text, 
DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), false, roles.Substring(1, roles.Length - 1), FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
string hashCookies = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, hashCookies);
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
}
```

then you can check the user, if he lies in certain role

```
 if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Super Admin"))
 {
  ...................
 }
```

Comment: :thanx. i can set dynamic roles. but how can i control permissions of each user separately ? thank u.

Comment: thanx & sry about wasting ur time but i dont mean my user may be lies in a certain role . i mean i have to control my user from two independent tables 1=>roles , 2=> permissions to forms. and how can i config it dynamically .thanx ever so much Muhammad.

Comment: There is direct config available for that purpose. What Actually you need, if you user have certain role and that role have certain permission, you need to check it, whether user lies in certain role and that particular role have have certain permission.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you could build a custom forms authentication provider in this case.

Here is an example
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-security/AspNetCustomAuth.aspx